# Distribute Hotel Beds According to Population Density in Buffers using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, intersection

I am running an ArcGIS for Desktop analysis where I am plotting competing hotel facilities and then distributing their beds in a 5-mile buffer around the site.

I would like to distribute the beds such that they are distributed according to where the population resides within that 5-mile radius, as opposed to evenly across the buffer.

That way, when I run an intersect - if the buffers overlap on top of a densely populated area, it will pick up more beds than if the same area overlapped on top of a sparsely populated area.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have population polygons at a reasonably small scale (e.g., census block groups)?

Comment: You may want to consider [location-allocation analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004700000050000000) for this.  Also, I think it would help your question if you were to include a picture of what you are trying to describe.

Comment: That's a great link @PolyGeo, I've not encountered that one before. When you say *site* ARM20, are you referring to a *work site* and not a *hotel site* in order to ascertain how many hotel beds are available for each work site?